# Removing Quotation marks in python output from string and list

Tags: python

I have to implement a function that takes a parameter of type string and parses this parameter and returns a tuple with the first value of the tuple being the number of units and the second value of the tuple the measurement unit. I was successful in splitting the number and measurement unit, but I need help with the quotation placement.

```
input_value = "3 ft"
split_list = (input_value.split())
print(split_list)
['3', 'ft']
```

How do I go about getting an output that looks like `[3, "ft"]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
input_value = "3 ft"
split_list = (input_value.split())
try:
    split_list[0] = int(split_list[0])
except ValueError:
    split_list[0] = float(split_list[0])
print(split_list) [3, 'ft']
```

Comment: what about if it was like 3.5 ft? I tried to use float instead of int, but quotations are back.

Comment: @Justice edited. Guaranteed to work if the first part is definitely an int or float.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the first element of the `split_list`, i.e., the three in your example to an `int` if you do not want quote marks around the number of units.

As for getting double quotes around the measurement unit, by default Python prints strings using single quotes, but you can use [json.**dumps**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) as a workaround since [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) strings have to use double quotes:

```
import json

input_value = "3 ft"
split_list = input_value.split()
split_list[0] = int(split_list[0])
print(json.dumps(split_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, "ft"]
```

---

If you need to support decimals e.g., `3.5 ft` use `float()` instead of `int()`:

```
import json

input_value = "3.5 ft"
split_list = input_value.split()
split_list[0] = float(split_list[0])
print(json.dumps(split_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[3.5, "ft"]
```

Try it **[here](https://repl.it/repls/TightWornProfiles#main.py)**.

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggested

What you can do is to convert the value of the list using `function`. So, it will be *hackable edited* when ever you want to add more formating to it.

#### Code

**List**

```
alist = ['3', 'ft']
```

**Function**

```py
def lista(alist):
    number, measure = alist
    number = int(number)
    alist = [number, measure]
    return alist
```

**Calling Function**

```
print(alist)
print("print the list after conversion {}".format(lista(alist)))
```

***OUTPUT***

```
['3', 'ft']
print the list after conversion [3, 'ft']
```